# Reference request for different definitions of finite

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, cardinals

I understand that there are different definitions of finite. They are all equivalent over ZFC, and some of them are even equivalent over ZF, but not over weaker theories than ZF(C). I would like some texts that define various notions of finite, and develop the theory quite a bit.

Comment: In Enderton's " Elements of Set Theory", pg 133 he defines a set to be finite if and only if it is equinumerous ( there exists a bijection) to a natural number, Halmos has the same definition is his "Naive Set Theory" textbook.

Comment: Kunen, also defines finite the same way, in his "Foundations of Mathematics Book". I'm actually fairly pressed to see any other authors use a different definition.

Comment: There are a few exercises in Jech's AC book about a couple definitions of finite inequivalent over ZF.

Comment: Maybe it is worth checking whether you find something useful in the refences given on Wikipedia: [Finite set § Set-theoretic definitions of finiteness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_set#Set-theoretic_definitions_of_finiteness). (Here is a link to the [current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Finite_set&oldid=1165389094).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a book that treats this specifically - although there should be in my opinion - but below is a list of relevant papers, in chronological order. Personally I recommend starting with the introductions of the more recent papers.

I've made this CW, and I encourage others to add to it (but please keep the chronological ordering, I think that lends some clarity):

---

- 1958: Levy, [*The independence of various definitions of finiteness*](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm46/fm4611.pdf).
- 1988: Spišiak/Vojtáš, [*Dependences between definitions of finiteness*](https://www.ksi.mff.cuni.cz/%7Evojtas/MathPub/1988_DependencesBetweenDefinitionsFiniteness.pdf).
- 2004: Cruz/Dzhafarov/Hall, [*Definitions of finiteness based on order properties*](https://damir.math.uconn.edu/papers/finiteness.pdf).
- 2019: Brot/Cao/Fernandez-Breton, [*Finiteness classes arising from Ramsey-theoretic statements in set theory without choice*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.11025).